# Как отобразить историю раннее введённых пользователем слов на html-странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сейчас пользователь вводит слово, и если оно совпадает с половиной(целой частью от деления на 2) какого-либо слова из массива, выводится надпись "Найдено",а иначе "Не найдено"

Как сделать так, чтобы результаты поиска отображались на странице (слово и рядом найдено оно было или нет)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">

let input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
let p = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0]
let words = ["милая", "миленький", "ужасный"]; //аналог списка слов, хранящегося в БД

input.addEventListener('input', function() { 
  p.innerHTML = '';
  if (this.value.length > 1) {
    let part = getPart(this.value);
    for (let i in words) {
      if (part == getPart(words[i])) { //сравниваем половины слов
        p.innerHTML = 'Найдено';
        break;
      }
       else {p.innerHTML = 'Не найдено';
       break;
     }
    }
  }
});

function getPart(val) {
  return val.substring(0, Math.floor(val.length / 2)).toLowerCase();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду: на странице? вы имеете ввиду, передавались из БД в шаблон?

Comment: есть веб-страница, там в окошко пользователь вводит слово, потом программа сравнивает ввёденное слова со словами из массива let words = ["милая", "миленький", "ужасный"]. Если совпало, нужно чтобы на этой же веб-странице было что-то вроде таблицы где 1 столбец-слово, которое было введено, 2 столбец- результат поиска(найдено или нет)

Comment: так добавьте введенное слово в массив words

Comment: не понимаю вашу логику

Comment: Вы отредактировали ваше сообщение и мой ответ не совпал с тем, что вы написали. Вы используете термин `сохранялись`: относительно `html` вы выглядит некорректно. Вам надо это слово отобразить. И все равно не понятно, где у вас возникли проблемы?

Comment: Случайно отправила недописанный коммент, ладно...Проблемы с тем КАК отобразить результаты поиска на странице, я понятия не имею

Comment: ну вы же используете уже все, что вам нужно - `p.innerHTML`. Просто вместо "Найдено" впишите слово и результат сравнения

Comment: Сохраняйте слова в LocalStorage, если я правильно Вас понимаю.

Comment: +LocalStorage юзай